# Каким образом разбивать на группы в случае распределения «с длинным хвостом»?

Tags: python, статистика, анализ-данных

У меня есть данные по активности пользователей. Активность имеет распределение «с длинным хвостом», то есть большинство пользователей совершили одно – два действия, и один - два участника совершили несколько сотен действий. Гистограмма активности:

[image: Гистограмма активности]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, *каким образом разбить участников на группы?* В случае нормального распределения я бы воспользовался методом основанным на межквартильном размахе – отделил бы все, что больше Q3 +1.5*IQR и затем повторял бы, пока не осталась одна группа (мысль — получить группы с разными средними). Будет ли иметь смысл этот метод в данном случае? Если нет, какой метод следует использовать?

**Обновление**

Сделал логарифмирование переменной

```
pd_series = np.log1p(pd_series)
pd.DataFrame(pd_series).hist(bins=100)
```

Получилось такая картина

[image: log hist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала прологорифмировать а перед тем -  помолится, что-бы у вас было логнормальное распределение :-) А уж потом  -  бейте на интервалы, да и весь остальной анализ проводите. По окончанию -  не забудьте перейти от полученных результатов назад к исходным данным.

Comment: Ну судя по графику логарифмирование должно помочь )

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не могли бы вы привести фрагмент кода (будет супер на 
 python + pandas, но можно и на любом другом) демонстрирующий как именно это сделать?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Учитывая, что у вас бывают нулевые значения, лучше всего использовать `numpy.log1p` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Согласен с уважаемым CrazyElf. Но в любом случае придется малость проэксперементировать.  А в Pandas все просто df[column_new] = np.log1p(df[column])

Comment: @passant Обновил вопрос. Пока что вроде бы все также. Я что–то не верно понял?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Ну, виднее же стало ))  Можно ещё раз попробовать прологарифмировать, наверное. Или взять логарифм с другим основанием. Обычно помогало один раз логарифмировать, эх

Comment: Кстати, еще раз прочитал вопрос :-) и не очень понял, что вы хотите в итоге получить. Во-первых, для такого класса распределения межквартильное расстояние вообще имеет не много смысла. Во-вторых, поняте "среднего" тут тем более дискуссионное.  Поэтому я не знаю, зачем надо разбивать данные на группы, но  даже рисунок выше показывает, что посчитав количество попаданий в каждый "столбец" можно таким образом выявить и примерно равные по объему группы. Ну и применить повторное преобразование или другое основание можно попробовать.  Или проверить вообще другие распределения, например -  Пуассона.

Comment: @passant Моя конечная задача — определить, что влияет на активность участников. В виде первого шага хочу разбить всех участников на "статистически" разные группы. Затем сравнить признаки для групп. Подскажите, как подойти к такой задачи более верно?

Comment: Надо понимать, что для вашей задачи вообще-то нет объективной разбивки. (Кстати, как и при разбивке по квартилям при нормальном распределении). Поэтому любая будет более-менее приемлемой.  Ну, например, первые три столбика, последние N столбиков, те, которые правее "3" на втором графике,  и третья - все остальные.  И разницу искать между первым и третьим набором, понимая, что середина - она всегда будет неопределенной.

Comment: @passant Большое спасибо! Изучаю распределение Пуассона. Возможно, что–то натолкнет на новые мысли.